# how do i randomize the rotation of the points of distribute points in geometry nodes

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

This is what is have right now, im trying to make a throne made out of a pile of sculls.

[image]

Comment: I've edited your question so that the image shows correctly.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! ...the first thing I would recommend is to use a Blender version that is as up-to-date as possible.

Comment: Do you really want to randomize the rotations of your skulls? I think the point of using skulls is to make them look like skulls https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplica_Czaszek_w_Kudowie-Zdroju#/media/Plik:Poland_-_Czermna_-_Chapel_of_Skulls_-_interior_06.jpg so maybe slight rotations up to 30° on each axis?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady how do i change the rotation using geometry nodes?

Answer (score 0):

If you make your skull face $+y$ (Suzanne by default is $-y$; also I've moved her forward a little bit, though I could just increase extrusion), you can align euler to normal and then additionally rotate a little like so:

[image]

[image]